# What is the format of jQuery Flot data when passing in the data as variables

Tags: flot

I have been trying to create a jQuery Flot pie chart, but I can't get the "data" parameter to work. I have 0..6 values that should total to 100(%), and these values need to be added individually, one label value pair at a time.

All of the examples I have seen assume that the data values are hard wired, and unfortunately that is not the way the real world works. I need some real world examples of how to construct the label - data pairs that Flot uses.

Comment: Did you ask this very question a few hours ago?

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884325/flot-pie-chart-doesnt-show

Comment: I tried rephrasing it to drill down to the real issue, but I haven't yet got an answer to either phrasing of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working when I realized that the data is supposed to be in jSON object notation. The old light bulb may be dim, but not entirely out. Here's the code:

```
function updatePieChart() {
    if ('#pieChart') {
        var total = 0;
        var data = new Array();
        var verb = "";
        var dataIndex = 0;
        var count = 0;

        for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < 5; dataIndex++) {
            var duty = "DUTY_" + (dataIndex + 1);
            verb = getData(duty + "_SKILL");
            var d = getData(duty + "_PERCENTAGETIMESPENT");
            if (isNumeric(d)) {
                d = parseInt(d);
                if (d > 0) {
                    total += d;
                    if (verb == "") verb = duty + dataIndex;
                    var dataPoint = {
                        label: verb,
                        data: d
                    }
                    data[count++] = dataPoint;
                    log(dataPoint.label + ' = ' + dataPoint.data);
                }
            }
        }

        if (total != 100) {
            if (total < 100) {
                var missingDataNum = 100 - total;
                var dataPoint = {
                    label: '**MISSING**',
                    data: missingDataNum
                }
                data[count] = dataPoint;
                log(dataPoint.label + ' = ' + dataPoint.data);
            }
        }
        if ($.isFunction($.plot)) {
            log('Plot version: ' + $.plot.version);
            var pie = $.plot($('#pieChart'), data,
                {
                    series: {
                        pie: {
                            show: true,
                            label: {
                                show: true,
                                radius: 1,
                                formatter: function (label, series) {
                                    return '<div style="font-size:11px; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:black;">' + label + '<br />' + Math.round(series.percent) + '%</div>';
                                },
                                background: {
                                    opacity: 0.0
                                }
                            },
                            combine: {
                                color: '#999',
                                threshold: 0.05
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false,
                        labelFormatter: function (label, series) {
                            return '<b>' + label + '</b>';
                        }
                    }
                });
             }
        }
    }
}
```